# How do I access an array from a parent class in a child class?

Tags: java, parent-child, superclass, extends

I have a class where arrays are globally declared and `public` these arrays are initialized though methods in this class. They are not inside of a constructor. I have another class where I have used `extends` to allow me access to these values. Of course, I am recieving a null pointer exception. How would I go about fixing this? I do not need to override these arrays. JUst need to use them inside of methods to fill other arrays.

I have been at this for awhile now. My experience with java is still pretty minimal.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you everyone

An example of what I am talking about:

```
public class Parent{
  public double hey[ ];

  public double [] fillHey(){

  hey = new double[57]

  for(int k = 0; k<57; k++)
    {
         hey[k] = k+2;
    }
   }
 }
```

The child class:

```
public class Child extends Parent{

public double you[ ];

public double[ ] fillYou(){

you = new double[57];

 for(int k = 0; k<57; k++)
    {
         you[k] = (k+2) * hey[k];
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: You forgot to tag the question with the language.

Comment: Ah looks like @Damien has me covered thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not instantiate `hey` array in the constructor of either class so it is still null when you use it in the child class.

You can either

- instantiate it in a constructor
- or instantiate it inside `fillYou()` method in the child class (before it's used).

Comment: So if I bring it up with the same name from the Parent class, the compiler will recognize this?

Comment: Yes, it will recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access to the hey[] from the child class, you must call it like this:

```
double  a[] = super.hey;
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: I see. Didnt know about .super(). Would I have to change anything else to this code?

Comment: Take in count that super refers to the parent class, so, if parent class contains a public X attribute, you can access to it using super.X

Comment: It is the same for calling parent methods and constructors. Nos, with this information, hope you can figure out how to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. So would I have to instantiate it in a constructor in either class like @Szymon mentioned?

Comment: Yeah, I think you must first initialize the array in the constructor you're calling in order to be able to use it.